# Keep recent SMS received in TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to keep the recent received SMS to TextView, but when i close the app then open it again the TextView returns to empty is there a way to keep the recent received SMS in TextView even if its closes the app

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    TextView addressField  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
    TextView messageField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

    if(extras != null){

        String address = extras.getString("MessageNumber");
        String message = extras.getString("Message");
        addressField.setText(address);
        messageField.setText(message);

    }
```

}

SimpleSmsReceiver.java

```
private static final String TAG = "Message recieved";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage messages = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
    Intent smsIntent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    String sender = messages.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
    smsIntent.putExtra("MessageNumber", sender);
    smsIntent.putExtra("Message", messages.getMessageBody());
    if(PhoneNumberUtils.compare("12345", sender) | PhoneNumberUtils.compare("123456", sender) ) {
        context.startActivity(smsIntent);
        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Received From Device" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read up on how to persist data in Android. Here's a good starting point: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage. The stored preferences answer provided by @Mohsen is the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Shared Preferences` in your `SimpleSmsReceiver` class since you're only passing data to the `MainActivity` using `Intent` but this won't save the data for the next time user opens the app.

In your `SimpleSmsReceiver` (e.g):

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("YourKey", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("MessageNumber", sender);
editor.putString("Message", messages.getMessageBody())
editor.apply();
```

Then to retrieve those values inside your `MainActivity`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("YourKey", MODE_PRIVATE);
String messageNumber = prefs.getString("MessageNumber", null);
String message = prefs.getString("Message", null);
```

Comment: So it wont save the data on TextView? and what should i input in "Yourkey" and mode_private?

Comment: It will actually. It will save those data then you can get it and set the values inside your `TextView` or etc. "Yourkey" is the key, you can change it or don't. `mode_private` is the second paramater in `Shared Preferences` and you don't need to change it. Read : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences and this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Comment: ok thanks, after inputting this code i got error on getSharedPreferences saying that cannot resolve method . and should i replace the smsIntent.putExtra to editor.putString? will my function still work after doing that?

Comment: Yes, replace those. Well of course that won't work since you're trying to use it outside of the `Activity`. Use `getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences` or `getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences` before `getSharedPreferences..` in order to add the `Activity`'s context.